# Could make only one optimize call in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, optimization, sapply

I'm trying to find two `p`s for two binomial distributions with 5 successes (`q`) in 15 trials (`s`).

- For the FIRST of the two binomial distributions, I want ***left of "5"*** (i.e., **0 to 5**) to have a cumulative probability of **".05"** (`alpha`).
- For the SECOND of the two binomial distributions, I want ***right of "5"*** (i.e., **5 to 15**) to have a cumulative probability of **".05"**(`alpha`).

## Question

I can find the two `p`s by calling `optimize()` twice (see below). But I was wondering if there is a way I could make a single `optimize()` call to get the same answers?

```
q = 5 ; s = 15 ; alpha = .05

f1 <- function (q, s, p, alpha) {
  abs((pbinom(q = q, s = s, p)) - alpha)
  }

CI[1] = optimize(f1, interval = c(0, 1), alpha = alpha, s = s, q = q, tol = 1e-12)[[1]] 
## 0.5774437 (answer is correct)

f2 <- function(q, s, p, alpha){
  abs((pbinom(q = q - 1, s = s, p, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)
  }

CI[2] = optimize(f2, interval = c(0, 1), alpha = alpha, s = s, q = q, tol = 1e-12)[[1]]
## 0.141664 (answer is correct)
```

Comment: All this bold and all-caps text makes reading your question harder than necessary.

Comment: Not much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional argument to f use `mapply` here. With `mapply`, you can feed multiple arguments to a function in parallel. Here, we feed the lower.tail argument and the q argument. Note that `mapply` is just a convenience function and that you could get something similar with a `for` loop, once the additional argument is added to your function.

```
f <- function(q, s, p, alpha, lower.tail = TRUE){
    abs((pbinom(q = q, s = s, p, lower.tail = lower.tail)) - alpha)
}

mapply(function(q, x) optimize(f, interval = c(0, 1), alpha = alpha, s = s,
                               q = q, tol = 1e-12, lower.tail=x),
       c(q, q-1), c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

This return a matrix with the desired values

```
          [,1]        [,2]        
minimum   0.5774437   0.141664    
objective 4.32016e-09 1.626525e-10
```

Comment: @rnorouzian It is generally in bad taste to ping people, with these requests. Please do not make this a habit. That being I took a stab at it.

Comment: I do apologize, and once again thank you for your elegant answer.